# Drop or Delete Schema Postgresql via controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, multi-tenant, rails-postgresql

I have multi-tenant application rails with postgresql, 
i want to drop schema (schema name = subdomain) and delete or table on schema.

primitive code on controller, wkwkwk.
accounts_controller.rb

```
def destroy
        @account = Account.find(params[:id])
        conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
        conn.execute("DROP SCHEMA "+@account.subdomain)
    end
```

error message

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in AccountsController#destroy

PG::Error: ERROR:  cannot drop schema subdomain1 because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  table articles depends on schema subdomain1
table gambarinfos depends on schema subdomain1
table pages depends on schema subdomain1
table redactor_assets depends on schema subdomain1
table schema_migrations depends on schema subdomain1
table usersekolahs depends on schema subdomain1
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
: DROP SCHEMA subdomain1
```

any ideas?

thx

Comment: I think this article is very usefull http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2011/07/building-multi-tenant-rails-apps-with-postgresql-schemas/ best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem solved with

add CASCADE to `conn.execute("DROP SCHEMA "+@account.subdomain+" CASCADE")`